# Async function not being called on page creation

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a page where a user makes a "post" (like twitter/ig) upon clicking submit that post is sent to the backend via a post request and then the page routes to the "Main Page" which is basically a scaffold with a persistent bottom navigation bar that creates the body based on which icon (index) in the navigation bar is pressed. By default the index is 0 (first icon) so the corresponding body is shown which also shows the newly created posts the user made by performing a get request to the server. **But the problem is it doesn't show the posts unless I click hot reload.** Similarly if I navigate to a different page by clicking one of the icons and come back to the first page the posts are gone till I press hot reload again. **How can I ensure the posts are loaded each time the body/page is created?**

Cody for page displaying the posts:

```
class PostPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _PostPageState createState() => _PostPageState();
}

class _PostPageState extends State<PostPage> {
 ApiClient _client = ApiClient();

 String session;
 int userID;

 var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

 Future GetInfo() async{
   session = await getSession("session");
   print("from get info "+ session);
   userID = await getUserID("userID");
   print("from get info "+ userID.toString());

 }

 @override
 void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
   GetInfo();
   print("called");

 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return DefaultTabController(
     length: 2,
     child: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("Posts", style: Style.AppBarStyle),
         bottom: TabBar(
           tabs: [
             Tab(
               text:  "Text1",
             ),
             Tab(
               text: "Text2",
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ),
       body: TabBarView(
         children: [

          Posts(_client.getPostsOne(userID, session)),
           Posts(_client.getPostsTwo(userID, session)),

         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Code for the future builder Posts:

```
Widget Posts(Future<List<Post>> future) {
  return FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
      future: future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Color(0xFF585B8D), Color(0xFF252642)])),
              child: CustomScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: false,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
                    sliver: SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (context, index) => PostCard(
                            snapshot.data[index], false, true, false),
                        childCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ));
        }
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Color(0xFF585B8D), Color(0xFF252642)])),
              child: Container());
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      });
}
```

**EDIT** It seemed like the GET request was being made before the userID/session key was loaded from shared preferences, adding setState({}) fixed this because it caused the widget to be repainted with the now retrieved userID/session key. But two get requests were made instead of one, to prevent this I checked if the session was null before calling or else I displayed an empty container.

```
 session !=null?Posts(_client.getPostsOne(userID, session)):Container()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `setState` after you get the data (to rebuild the widget):

```
    Future GetInfo() async{
       session = await getSession("session");
       print("from get info "+ session);
       userID = await getUserID("userID");
       print("from get info "+ userID.toString());
       setState(() {

          });

     }
```

Comment: This solved my problem! When I switch from different icons and go back there seems to be a short delay/lag before my post appears is there anyway I can deal with this?

Comment: It's an async call so before you get the userID you could display a CircleProgressIndicator.
After you get the userID you willl refresh the widget and the indicator should be removed